# Complex insert based on few subqueries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have following tables:

```
Posts: id, CategoryId
PostAssociations: PostId FK Posts(id), AssociatedPostId FK Posts(id)
```

So each post may have many other posts as associated posts.

What I need is:

For each post P that does not have any associated posts yet, add 4 random associated posts from the same category (excluding post P - it should not be associated to himself).

So far I have

```
# SELECT Posts that don't have any associated posts yet
SELECT p.id
FROM "Posts" p
LEFT OUTER JOIN "PostAssociations" pa ON pa."PostId" = p.id
WHERE pa."PostId" IS NULL
```

And:

```
# SELECT 4 random posts from given category and excluding given id
SELECT id 
FROM "Posts" p2
WHERE p2."CategoryId" = ? AND p2.id != ?
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 4
```

I need query like this:

```
INSERT INTO "PostAssociations" VALUES ...
```

---

SQL fiddle with explanation what I need: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ba735/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tagged the post with postgresql-9.3 I guess using `LATERAL`to apply the random id generating query over all ids that are missing associations should work. (This should be functionally similar to using `OUTER APPLY`with MS SQL for instance).

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/60b61/32) (showing before, insert and after).

```
INSERT INTO PostAssociations
SELECT 
  p.id, rand.id rand
FROM Posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN PostAssociations pa ON pa.PostId = p.id
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(
  SELECT id 
  FROM Posts
  WHERE CategoryId = p.categoryid AND id != p.id
  ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 4) AS rand ON TRUE
WHERE pa.PostId IS NULL;
```

I can't claim to be an expert with Postgresql so it's quite possible the query can be improved.